# Zabbix frontend Error connecting to database

Tags: database-connection, zabbix

I am having a problem at zabbix web interface, it won't connect to the database as I receive this error: Error connecting to database.
Here are two screenshots from both files:
[/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBdwz.png)

[/usr/share/zabbix/conf/zabbix.conf.php.example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TDdt.png)

Any help?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you renamed the zabbix.conf.php.example to zabbix.conf.php and put your db logins there?

Comment: @AndréSchild I have just tried it. Still the same error

Comment: You haven't mentioned the DB['PORT'] in the /usr/share/zabbix/conf/zabbix.conf.php.example file make sure the port in the file and restart the zabbix server and check

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem with Centos+Postgre+Zabbix stack. And problem was with ident auth:

1. You need go to /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf (default path)
2. and change `ident` in this:

`host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident`

`host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident`

to `md5`

3. After this restart postgresql service and you can check connection by command:

   psql -h localhost -U <your_zabbixdb_user> <your_zabbix_db>

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you access to a shell and connect to the zabbix database directly ?
2. In your configuration files, it seems that you use PostgreSQL.
   It is written that you have to indicate the `DBSchema` variable if you use PostgreSQL.

   However you didn't declare it.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the password should be in quotation marks: `DBPassword="zabbix"`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. It is resolved by changing "Database host" from localhost to 127.0.0.1 in DB connection and changing the pg_hba.conf as below

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            password
```

[Zabbix GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rs65V.png)